# ASP.NET MVC : cannot retrieve hours, minutes, seconds from SQL database, they always show 12:00

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, datetime, dotnetnuke

**Note**: I am also looking for a way to `AddWithParameter` to avoid the SQL injection risk, but I am not sure how to do that with DotNetNuke so that is a second question to this matter.

I am storing date as C# `DateTime` into SQL database `datetime` column. When retrieving that date I cannot obtain the hh:mm:ss information, it always displays 12:00, but the Day, Month, Year are retrieved and displayed correctly.

This is how I insert the date in SQL:

```
string sqlDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";               
string sqlInsertString = String.Format("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Date_Column_Name) VALUES ({0})", thisDate?.ToString(sqlDateFormat)};

using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
{
    try
    {                  
        ctx.Execute(System.Data.CommandType.Text, 
        sqlInsertString);      
        success = true;                                                     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how I retrieve the table data:

```
using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
{
    string sqlString = @"SELECT Date_Column_Name FROM Table_Name  WHERE ID = " + paramId;

    try
    {
        myTableDates = ctx.ExecuteQuery<TableModel> (System.Data.CommandType.Text, sqlString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how I try to display in view:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (TableModel tm in Model.AllTablesDates)
    {
        var dateVar = tm.Date == null ? "N/A" : 
        tm.Date.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm tt");

        <tr>
            <td data-title="Day">@dateVar</td>                        
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Don't use `String.Format` for creating your Sql command. Use parameterized queries. You are opening yourself up for Sql Injection attacks.

Comment: @gunr2171 you're right but I am using DNN and i am nto sure how you add with parameter using DontNetNuke. As you cann see I am using IDataContext from DNN and i did not see any AddWithParamater option.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the data type of the column in your database is datetime, and not date?

Comment: @hatchet yes it's definitely datetime I checked again

Comment: Also, if anyone would like to point out how I can add with paramater in DotNetNuke I would be very grateful.

Comment: `ctx.Execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Date_Column_Name)VALUES (@0)", thisDate)`. [Source](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/147320/dal-2-datacontext-deep-dive)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto rather be safe than sorry. Second code block uses string concatenation. I have no idea from here what data type it is - could be an int - could be something else in the future.

Comment: @gunr2171 Huh, I didn't see that second block correctly, nevermind :)

Comment: @EmilRR1 `ExecuteQuery<TableModel>` receives a last argument `params object[] args`, pass your parameters there. See [here](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/147320/dal-2-datacontext-deep-dive) listing 6

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Would love to know how to do that, could you please provide a code sample if its not too much to ask

Comment: @EmilRR1 See the link I provided, search for "listing 6" in that page

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks will study the link

Comment: Can you open your table with SQL Server Explorer in Visual Studio and select the inserted rows there? That is to check whether the correct value with time goes into Database. By that you can find out whether the problem is at inserting or at retrieving the data. Second, 12:00 as time might lead to a line of code where you accidently access the "Date" property of your DateTime object (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @TorbenSchramme The dates are entered, at least the DAY, MONTH, YEAR just not sure if the hours, minutes, seconds are entered correctly or retrieved correctly as you said. Any way to check whether the hours, minutes, seconds were entered correctly that you can suggest

Comment: What is being asked of you is to check the schema type for that column. You need to see if the type supports a time aspect. Ideally it should be of type [`DateTime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) with a precision of 3 or more *but* if you only want to capture the date then use `Date` instead. What you should **not do** is use `char`/`varchar` or other text types to capture Date or DateTime data. If you find that the schema type is some string representation then you need to redesign your schema.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for that info, will check the schema

Comment: @Igor its just datetime

Comment: @Update: The hh:mm:ss info is not entered correctly into db. That is why its not retrieved. I am still not sure why though. Tried hard coding '2019/02/25 12:09:44' in an insert and its still not displaying in the column.

Comment: Ok so the problem is most likely at inserting the values. Can you please try to format the date in ISO 8601? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 So that there is a T as a separator between date and time (2004-05-23T14:25:10). sqlDateFormat = "s" should do the job (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable)

Comment: Did you do what I suggested above because that should fix it? `ctx.Execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Date_Column_Name)VALUES (@0)", thisDate)`

Comment: @Igor sorry for late reply but yes that fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/147320/dal-2-datacontext-deep-dive) change your statement to the following:

```
ctx.Execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Date_Column_Name)VALUES (@0)", thisDate);
```